# Excel Chart not showing SOME X-axis labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have a chart that refreshes after a dataload, and it seems like when there are more than 25 labels on the x-axis, the 26th and on do not show, though all preceding values do.  Also, the datapoints for those values show in the chart.  In the chart data window, the labels are blank.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they showing up on the graph itself?  Could you post the "Series X Values" definition (from clicking on "edit" in the shot you posted.)  Also post a shot of the corresponding range on your sheet.

Comment: no, they are not showing on the graph itself either.  They ARE showing in the data range in the sheet though.

Comment: Could you post the "Series X Values" definition (from clicking on "edit" in the shot you posted.) Also post a shot of the corresponding range on your sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem I think it's somewhat related to what was brought up in this [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/excel-chart-horizontal-axis-labels-wont-update/ad08e563-08c2-4649-a92c-27894b23f072), although I didn't really follow. What I did to make it work was the following:

- On the legend entries (series) section I clicked edit for each series and confirmed they were the right series.
- I think clicked "edit" on the Horizontal (category) Axis labels and confirmed it was the correct selection (in my case I had to extend the range to incorporate added data)
- Once this was complete the values showed up in the horizontal (category) Axis labels and when I selected them it populated my chart.

I recognize this is only a work around so if anyone knows the root cause and how to prevent it that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Mine disappeard because the Column with the data was hidden.  Unhiding the column fixed it.  Not sure why this is related.

Answer (score 0):

I right-clicked on the x-axis and then played around with the 'major units' field, until all the labels I required showed.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013, select the bar graph or line chart whose axis you're trying to fix. Right click on the chart, select "Format Chart Area..." from the pop up menu. A sidebar will appear on the right side of the screen. On the sidebar, click on "CHART OPTIONS" and select "Horizontal (Category) Axis" from the drop down menu. Four icons will appear below the menu bar. The right most icon looks like a bar graph. Click that. A navigation bar with several twistys will appear below the icon ribbon. Click on the "LABELS" twisty. You can play with the options under here to get your X axis looking how you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and it was only due to what excel can fit in the chart. Click the chart, and then drag one of the sizing handles to enlarge the chart. By default, the fonts in the chart scale proportionally as you resize the chart. Once you make your chart big enough, your labels should show.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. I found that excel had trouble picking up the values from cells which had been merged. Once i de-merged the values appeared in my chart.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Finally was able to select data manually for the "chart data range." The blank x-axis categories were not being pulled in, though the numerical data was. It was bizarre and annoying but I was eventually able to get the darn labels to show.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicked on the horizontal axis and selected Format Axis.  Changed axis type from automatic to text and the missing labels appeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was on **Format Axis** | **Axis Options**, **Bounds** had a custom value for **Maximum**; [I hit the **Reset** button to switch back to **Auto**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4djG.png), and all the missing values were displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to right click on the chart, go to the "Select Data" option. In the box, check each Legend Entry and ensure the corresponding Horizontal Labels are fully filled in. I found for me only one Legend had the full X-axis list, but there was one that didn't and this meant half of my X-axis labels were blank.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the X axis/dates not adding additional months. In the "Select Data" field, I had to "uncheck" the earlier months to get the later months to show up. It seems like Excel has a limit to the number of X-axis fields. Not a good solution since you lose the initial months, but enabled the most current data to show up.

Date Field

[image: Date Field]