# My Line Chart Isn't Showing All Axis Labels

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anybody know why my line graph is only showing some of the axis labels and not all? It makes reading the chart rather difficult having it miss out labels like it's doing...

[image]

Comment: Please check if the methods in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1195816/excel-chart-not-showing-some-x-axis-labels) are helpful. For reference:[Change the display of chart axes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/change-the-display-of-chart-axes-422c97af-1483-4bad-a3db-3a9ef630b5a9).

Answer (score 0):

Select the axis labels and right-click on it.

From the pop-up menu, choose `Format Axis...`

[image]

Under `Labels`, you can select the interval units

[image]